# Trying to receive emails AND store them into an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-s3, mx-record, amazon-ses

I'm trying to store emails i receive into an s3 bucket, i followed this tutorial and multiple others :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-getting-started.html

My MX record is set to my mail.Domain like this :
Domain MX 10 mail.domain
When i change it to
Domain MX 10 inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

I do not receive mails anymore and still do not get emails stored.

I do not know what is missing exactly ? someone help please.

**Update :** Managed to follow Mlu answer and i'm now at a very close step to getting my answer, the only problem is that AWS SES does not accept a "FROM" that is outside of my domain reaching another outside domain.

For example A sends email to B, B forwards (looks more like redirects) email to C, so C sees that he got a message from A not B, that, AWS SES doesn't like and will give this error for example :

554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1: OutsiderMail@gmail.com, Jon Doe  (in reply to end of DATA command).

Comment: Unfortunately this will be difficult for us to help you with, as you've provided no diagnostic information. I suggest you either find another tutorial, or hire an AWS Consultant who can work this out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some DNS / email background - even if you have multiple MX records for *example.com* in your DNS the emails are only received by **one of the servers** listed. Typically the sender contacts the one with the [*lowest* preference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) but in your case if both have *priority 10* the sender server will just choose one randomly.

If you want to both receive email on your *mail.example.com* **and** through *AWS SES* to store it in S3 you will have to **feed it from one to the other** explicitly.

I've got a similar setup in one of our projects and we receive the mails by Postfix (that's our *mail.example.com*) and from there we forward it to SES using the [`always_bcc`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#always_bcc) postfix configuration directive.

In this case the *example.com* MX record only points to *mail.example.com*, not to SES. However we also have a record for *ses.example.com* being a MX record pointing to *inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com*. Then our `always_bcc = prod-bcc@ses.example.com` and obviously in SES we've got the domain `ses.example.com` configured to store emails to S3.

If you want you can also do it the other way around - receive on SES first and from there save to S3 and forward to your other mail server.

The bottom line is that you can'y simply list both SES and the mail server and expect that the emails will arrive to both. You have to explicitly receive at one and forward to the other.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104116/discussion-on-answer-by-mlu-trying-to-receive-emails-and-store-them-into-an-s3-b).

Comment: Hi, here is the new thread :
https://serverfault.com/questions/1002025/how-to-use-ses-as-an-outbound-relay-for-postfix