# How to use SES as an outbound relay for Postfix

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, postfix, amazon-s3, zimbra

I'm looking for a way to both receive emails and then store them in s3 at the same time while using ses, i found out that it can't be done unless i do some way of forwarding, so, what i did was that i created an additional subdomain "ses.example.com" and Linked it in DNS (MX) to inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, and then created an email adress called forward@ses.example.com and configured it under ses to store s3 (using rule sets), in addition to this, i used "always_bcc" configuration to forward all mails to the address forward@ses.example.com, by doing so, i managed to receive and store only locally sent mails, mails coming from outside will not be stored, i think that is happening because when the mails are forwarded, the "from" header stays the same, but, i'm not really sure, is there a way around this ?

I just need to know if there is a way to use ses to both store emails in S3 and receive them to my mailserver at the same time.

tell me if you need more information please.

I'm using Zimbra mail server with postfix.

This is how my dns looks like :

Example.com MX 10 mail.example.com.
ses.example.com 10 MX inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has a great how-to for setting up SES as a Postfix relay: [**Integrating Amazon SES with Postfix**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/postfix.html).

Note that you will have to **verify** your domain(s) as valid senders in SES because SES won't let you spoof emails from any random domain that you choose.

That also means that you won't be able to *forward* emails through Postfix to other recipients as they would be sent with their original sender address (e.g. @gmail.com) which isn't allowed/verified in your SES configuration.

In relation to your [other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1001623/trying-to-receive-emails-and-store-them-into-an-s3-bucket) - **forwarding *to* SES** for S3 backup purposes has to be done through a *domain-specific rule* in `/etc/postfix/transport`. Something like this:

```
ses.example.com    smtp:inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

See [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/257637/postfix-to-relay-mails-to-other-smtp-for-particular-domain#257640) for more details on that.

Hope that helps :)